# linux how to cd to parent folder if navigated through a symlink

Tags: bash, symlink, cd-command, shell-builtin

I have following symlink in my home directory.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mtk mtk   43 Aug  8 20:35 tripple-bit -> /media/mtk/study/Collage/docs
```

I use the symlink to navigate to the `docs` folder directly. But now, while being in `docs` folder, I want to move to it's parent directory i.e. `/media/mtk/study/Collage` in this case.

How can I achieve this?

On giving `cd ..`, it comes back to the home directory and not the parent directory.

Comment: Try `cd -P`. The `-P` option tells `cd` to use the physical directory layout when resolving relative paths.

Comment: And just for completness `cd -L ..` is other way around - change directory logically.

Comment: What shell? this is a shell question not a kernel question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
cd -P ..
```

From the bash manpage:

> The -P option says to use the physical directory structure instead of
>   following symbolic links.